# Is there any map in C++ which can store duplicate values and in same order as order of insertion?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to code solution for this [Diagonal Traversal of Binary Tree](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/diagonal-traversal-of-binary-tree/1/#).
I got easy solutions from editorial, but want to improve my code.
I am using multimap but insertion order is not preserved.

Is there any map in c++ where I can store duplicate value and in the order of insertion.
I tried using unordered_multimap but does not works

```
vector<int> diagonal(Node *root)
{
    vector<int>v;
    if(root == NULL){
        return v;
    }
    
    queue<pair<Node*,int>>q;
    int level = 0;
    unordered_multimap<int,int>mp;
    
    q.push({root,level});
    
    mp.insert(pair<int, int>(root->data,level));
    q.push({NULL,0});
    
    while(!q.empty()){
        // pair<int,int> p = q.front();
        Node *f = q.front().first;
        int h = q.front().second;
        
        q.pop();
        
    if(f == NULL){
            if(!q.empty()){
            q.push({NULL,0});
        }
    }
        
    else{
     
       if(f->left){
           
        q.push({f->left,h+1});
        mp.insert(pair<int, int>(f->left->data,h+1));
        if(h+1 > level)
        level = h+1;
        
        }
        
        if(f->right){
        q.push({f->right,h});
        mp.insert(pair<int, int>(f->right->data,h));
        }
        }
        }
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= level+1; i++){
            
            for(auto itr = mp.begin(); itr != mp.end(); itr++){
                if(itr->second == i){
                v.push_back(itr->first);
                
                }
            }
            
        }
      return v;  
        
    }
```

The output of this code :
[image: Results]

I want to print the nodes in right order, as in expected outcome.
If any other data structure can help instead of maps, that will also be okay.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`? `unordered_map` didn't work because it still maintains some order, it's just that you can't control it.

Comment: Since C++11, `std::multimap::insert(value_type)` is supposed to put the new element after any existing elements with equivalent key. (`unordered_multimap` has no such requirement, of course.) But since you're putting `{data, height}`, the multimap is sorted by data value, not by height. Unless I'm missing something, don't you want height as the key, and then you can just read off the whole multimap in its own order?

Comment: Use both std::vector and std::set. Former for order, latter for uniqueness.